# How do I import show_simple_view from enaml.stdlib.sessions?

Tags: python, enaml

I'm trying to teach myself Enaml but none of the tutorial code works for me. http://docs.enthought.com/enaml/instructional/tut_hello_world.html

Whenever I execute the Python code, it stops at line 8:

from enaml.stdlib.sessions import show_simple_view

and gives the error:

ImportError: No module named sessions

I have Enaml and all of it's dependencies. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs you are looking at are for a very old version of enaml which is quite different than the current version.

Development of enaml moved several years ago from enthought's github repo to https://github.com/nucleic/enaml, where the current version is 0.9.7, and where you will find more current docs.

[Enthought's free Canopy Express](https://www.enthought.com/downloads/) currently includes enaml 0.9.4.

If you do `pip install enaml` as suggested by @alfasin, you'll get version 0.9.1 (as of this writing). Anaconda also includes this version.

Answer (score 1):

Try running from command line: `pip install enaml`

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this docs: 
http://nucleic.github.io/enaml/docs/get_started/anatomy.html

If you have installed from new git repo.